# count syllables in txt files in R

Tags: r, count

I'm totally new to R. So bear with me if the question is silly ;）

I have 20 txt files and I want to know how to count syllables in each txt.

I tried to use **nsyllable**. In the example it's like this:

usage:

```
nsyllable(x, language = "en", syllable_dictionary = NULL, use.names = FALSE)
```

Arguments

example:

```
nsyllable(c("cat", "syllable", "supercalifragilisticexpialidocious",
            "Brexit", "Administration"), use.names = TRUE)
```

**what I want to know is how to convert txt files into vectors so that I can replace single words such as "cat" with a txt file. And hopefully the output can be listed in a table so that I can export it.**

Hope someone can hlep. Thx!

Comment: Welcome to SO (and to the world of R) - this is relatively basic stuff, so if you search for "import txt file into R" and "separate strings into words in R" you will find many beginner tutorials that can guide you through this process.  If you run into specific issues along the way, then Stack Overflow is a good place to bring those.